# 0 view but 2 answers, the main page works in a strange way?

Tags: support

Why my question get 0 view but 2 answers? I think the main page is not work correctly, could you please fix it.

[image]

Comment: They didn't view the page, they projected their answer with "the force"

Comment: Should this question be resolved then?

Answer (score 6):

The 'views' count is heavily cached. This effect is much more apparent for smaller, newer sites. Give it time; the display will catch up.